# How to set the selected value of Select Option in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I am retreiving users and their id in Laravel. I retrieved the selected user ID and their full names. I want to set the selected option according to the current ID.

This is the value of the current user ID:

```
<input class="selected-user" type="input" value="{{$selectedUser}}" readonly />
```

This is my select code in Laravel Blade:

```
        <div class="form-group required">

            {!! Form::label('user_name', 'Assigned to', ['class' => 'control-label required']) !!}

            <div class="controls">

                <select class="form-control form-field-username form-field-user-edit form-field-users">
                    @foreach($users as $user)
                        <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->getFullNameAttribute()}} </option>
                    @endforeach 
                </select>

            </div>                      

        </div>
```

This is my jquery code:

```
var selectedUser = $('.selected-user').val();

    $('.form-field-user-edit > option[value="selectedUser"]').attr('selected','selected');
```

The above code is not working.

I want to mark the select selected option according to the value **.selected-user**

Comment: since there are already 3 answers, i would recommend to add the additional line to your code $(".form-field-use-edit").selectmenu("refresh", true);

Comment: ok sir. thank you. i wonder what does that "refresh" do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.. You can select the option from server side

```
<select class="form-control form-field-username form-field-user-edit form-field-users">
    @foreach($users as $user)
         <option value="{{$user->id}}" {{ $selectedUser== $user->id ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}>{{$user->getFullNameAttribute()}} </option>
    @endforeach 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

You should instead do this on the server side using the html. The link I pasted is about the  tag, and down the list you see an attribute called "selected". if this is present in your tag, it will be selected:

```
<option value="?" selected> This option is selected </option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the line of code from,

```
 $('.form-field-user-edit > option[value="selectedUser"]').attr('selected','selected');
```

to

```
$('.form-field-user-edit > option[value="selectedUser"]').attr('selected',true);
```

Comment: Thanks. the option was mark selected but the it does not set as the FIRST  OPTION. do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var selectedUser = $('.selected-user').val();

$('.form-field-user-edit > option[value="'+ selectedUser +'"]').prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: Thanks. the option was mark selected but the it does not set as the FIRST  OPTION.. hmm...